# Hardhat error HH501, couldn't download compiler version Mac

Tags: compiler-errors, version, solidity, hardhat

When doing `yarn hardhat test`, I get: `Error HH501: Couldn't download compiler version 0.5.16. Please check your connection.` Doing `solc-select install 0.5.16` doesn't do anything. I saw some recommendations online about adding an HTTP proxy but that seems sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error message however I am running `yarn hardhat compile`. I was able to solve the error with `sudo yarn hardhat compile`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error was that it didn't have permission to access the solidity directory. I had to `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/hardhat-nodejs` first. You may have to `solc-select` install the new solidity version manually, or chmod a different directory depending on where you are calling hardhat from (which you can see by manually calling in verbose mode).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working perfectly by running `yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan chai ethers hardhat-gas-reporter solidity-coverage @typechain/hardhat typechain @typechain/ethers-v5 @ethersproject/abi @ethersproject/providers` in my vs code terminal then I had to use the command `yarn hardhat compile` 4 times. Also make sure that the solidity versions are consistent in files like "Lock.sol", "hardhat.config.js", etc.

Answer (score 0):

A beginner way to do it to bypass the problem, is to do the following:

1. Download the Js file for the compiler `soljson-vxx.xx.js`. If you use Visual Studio Code, just right click your solidity contract and download the correct compiler. The downloaded file will be placed in root directory of your project.
2. Replace the current version `”PROJECT DIRECTORY"\node_modules\solc` with the newly downloaded file.
3. Recompile using hardhat. It should be able to download the compiler.